# How can i manipulate my list?

Tags: python, list

```
data = ['10', '0', '1915', '387', '1933', '402']
```

That is the kind of data i have.
what i want is to compare `data[2]` with `data[4]` 
and `data[3]` with `data[5]`
and put inside `data[2]` the value of the bigger `data[2]` or `data[4]`
same with `data[3]` and `data[5]`

so the end result for this example would be :

```
['10', '0', '1933', '402', '1915', '382']
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `max()` ?
https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max

Comment: I think there is a typo. Is `382` meant to be `387`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
data = ['10', '0', '1915', '387', '1933', '402']

# Convert strings to int
result = [int(i) for i in data]

# sorted works with numeric values.
# This uses tuple unpacking, even though sorted returns a list
result[2], result[4] = sorted([result[2], result[4]], reverse=True)  
result[3], result[5] = sorted([result[3], result[5]], reverse=True)

# cast ints back to str as per spec
result = [str(i) for i in result]
```

This is the output:

```
>>> data = ['10', '0', '1915', '387', '1933', '402']
... 
... # Convert strings to int
... result = [int(i) for i in data]
... 
... # sorted works with numeric values.
... # This uses tuple unpacking, even though sorted returns a list
... result[2], result[4] = sorted([result[2], result[4]], reverse=True)  
... result[3], result[5] = sorted([result[3], result[5]], reverse=True)
... 
... # cast ints back to str as per spec
... result = [str(i) for i in result]
>>> result
['10', '0', '1933', '402', '1915', '387']
```

Comment: This was the output `['10', '0', '387', '402', '0', '1915']`

Comment: @user9282640 You didn't copy-and-paste the answerer's code.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one, just to have options:

```
swap = [(2, 4), (3, 5)]

for s in swap:
    if int(data[s[1]]) > int(data[s[0]]):
        data[s[0]], data[s[1]] = data[s[1]], data[s[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(2, len(data),2):
    if i+2 < len(data) and data[i+2] > data[i]:
        temp  = data[i]
        data[i] = data[i+2]
        data[i+2] = temp
```

Comment: this was the output of your code `['10', '0', '402', '387', '1933', '1915']`

Comment: Please run on correct array. ['10', '0', '1933', '387', '1915', '402']

Answer (score 0):

If the task in hand is to code it manually;

Create a list that we will use to assert the data to at the end. This will be used to store the new order of the list you want

```
order_list = []
```

We insert the first and second elements of data as this is not being manipulated or re-ordered.

```
order_list.append(data[0])
order_list.append(data[1])
```

now we check which is bigger out of data[2] and data[4]

```
if data[2] > data[4]:
    order_list.append(data[2])
else:
    order_list.append(data[2])
```

Then repeat this with data elements 3 and 5.

You can then assign that new list to be data, by `data = order_list` or return the new list.

If the task does not require you to do this; there is a built in function max() that returns the largest of two elements passed into the function

Answer (score 0):

As you want the items in your list to be swapped, and not just set to the max, the following code works:

```
def swap(list, i, j):
    buffer = list[i]
    list[i] = list[j]
    list[j] = buffer
    return list

data = ['10', '0', '1915', '387', '1933', '402']

print(data)

if data[4] > data[2]:
    swap(data, 4, 2)

if data[5] > data[3]:
    swap(data, 5, 3)

print(data)
```